# Hotel booking for a couple, Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas, proof-of-accommodation

I am booking hotels/hostels in Europe through booking.com. Soon I'll apply for a Schengen visa. The problem is, all the third-party sites like Booking, Agoda, Expedia show only my name as the guest. Shouldn't the confirmation email show my spouse's name also? Otherwise, how is he going to prove his accommodation booking to the embassy?

I'm yet to find a source from where I can book with free cancellation and the booking will show both person's names. Does anybody have any recommendation?

Comment: The booking should show 2 guests, and the visa applications should show you’re travelling together?

Answer (score 7):

As of November 2023, Booking.com allows you to put multiple names in the booking:

[image: Multiple guest names]

All names would be printed on the booking confirmation.

***A note regarding the previous answer***:

> A reservation for two guests in the name of one spouse should be sufficient evidence of accommodation for both spouses. Consider this from the point of view of a visa officer. Your husband's visa application will show that he is planning to travel with you. The application will include a hotel booking in your name for two guests. The only logical conclusion is that this booking is intended to accommodate both you and your husband.

While this works most of the time, it's not always the case.
I've applied for Schengen visa for my wife and myself several times.
On the first 2 times (Italian & German consulates) we used one hotel booking under my name. Both times the visa officer accepted it for both mine and my wife's visa application.

A few years later we applied for another Schengen Visa (*to the same German consulate*). This time however, the visa officer refused to accept the hotel booking made under my name for my wife's application even though we were travelling together.

Answer (score 2):

A reservation for two guests in the name of one spouse should be sufficient evidence of accommodation for both spouses.  Consider this from the point of view of a visa officer.  Your husband's visa application will show that he is planning to travel with you.  The application will include a hotel booking in your name for two guests.  The only logical conclusion is that this booking is intended to accommodate both you and your husband.

Comment: "The only logical conclusion is that this booking is intended to accommodate both you and your husband." Are there any official guidelines about it? Relying purely on logic in the situations where bureaucracy is involved is not very reliable, imo.

Comment: I had done the same and they didn't even ask any question. Czech embassy in Singapore.